# How to show the total number of visitors to my website?

Tags: asp.net

I am developing an ASP.NET **intranet** web application that provides short quizzes to the users in the company. I want now to count the number of all visitors to the website either they took some quizzes or just come to the website and read some information like downloading the newsletter or reading some general information.

How to do that? Should I have a special table in the database for this thing?

Also, it will be very helpful if there is any helpful free tool like Google Analytics. As you know, the policy of the company doesn't allow to use the Google Analytics.

Comment: Do you want to count the number of visitors, or the number of visits? That is, if Fred uses your site three times, is that one visitor or three?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could log the count in a database and simply increment it by 1 in the session start for a total of all time.

If it's concurrent you are after, store the data as an application variable and decrease the count on session end.

I don't see why you don't use an analytics package on your server logs though.

Comment: Is counting sessions accurate? Doesn't it count duplicates?

Comment: If a user returns before the timeout, the previous session will be used. It depends on whether you want concurrent or grand total.

Comment: Session_End is very unreliable for trying to count active users.

Comment: Doozer, this is something I here often but it's still the best system out there. The issue is the balance of session time. Too long and the count won't decrement quick enough. Too short and your session variables / features become useless.